# Indexing Error on comparing two Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am comparing column of 1 data frame with another and getting an `Indexing Error`

**My Code**:

```
##For reading and re-setting index
df1 = pd.read_excel(path) ## 776 line items
df2 = pd.read_excel(path1) ## 10k+ line items

df1.reset_index(inplace = True)
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)

## For comparing two columns
is_expired =df1['Contract Id'].isin(df2['Contract Id']) ## Series of 776 boolean True/False Created successfully
df3=df2.loc[:,is_expired] ## Getting Index error 
df3= df2[is_expired] ## Also tries this, same error
```

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index
>   of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

**Sample DF**

```
Df1

Contract ID     Name
CW 123           A
CW 125           B
                 C
                 D
```

Df2

```
Contract ID     Name_1
CW 123           Other
CW 124           Columns
CW 125           Don't
CW 1258          Matter
```

There are lot of answers in SO but everyone points on using `.loc` and the error will not come. But I am still getting the same error. Can someone please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mask has to match to DataFrame for filter, so if compare `df1['Contract Id']` then filter `df1`:

```
#test df1['Contract Id']
is_expired = df1['Contract Id'].isin(df2['Contract Id']) 
#filter df1
df3 = df1[is_expired]
```

Or if compare `df2['Contract Id']` filter `df2`:

```
#test df2['Contract Id']
is_expired = df2['Contract Id'].isin(df1['Contract Id']) 
#filter df2
df3 = df2[is_expired]
```

Reason why your solution fail is different mask and different filtered DataFrame:

```
#test df1['Contract Id']
is_expired = df1['Contract Id'].isin(df2['Contract Id'])
#filter df2
df3 = df2.loc[:,is_expired]
```

Comment: Still Same error...Forget to post in my question..but I tried this also!! My mask is working well!! the next line is giving error

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - hmmm, so filtered like first or second paragraph? Not like third?